# Letting user choose from 2 options for QGIS Processing script input parameter?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I want to make a drop down box that shows 2 or 3 options and let the user choose 1 from them?

I would like to let the user to choose from "millimeter", "centimeter" and "meter". These Options are not from the field of input.

It seems like none of them here is valid:

[image: It seems like none of them here is valid]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Germán Carrillo's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/4972/germ%c3%a1n-carrillo) answer is the most convenient. A possible alternative (if you're stuck with QGIS 2.8) could be to:

- Use a **string** which allows the user to enter the units they want to use:

  ```
  ##units=string mm

  if units == 'mm':
      # Do something
  elif units == 'cm':
      # Do something
  elif units == 'm':
      # Do something
  ```

  [image: Text units]

---

- Or use three boolean checkboxes:

  ```
  ##Millimeter=boolean
  ##Centimeter=boolean
  ##Meter=boolean

  if Millimeter == True:
      # Do something
  elif Centimeter == True:
      # Do something
  elif Meter == True:
      # Do something
  ```

  [image: Checkbox units]

Answer (score 9):

If you are not limited to QGIS v2.8 (your screenshot points to v2.8 documentation), you can install a newer version. For example, in QGIS v2.14 you have a `selection` parameter type available (see [the docs](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html)):

[image]

You can use it in this way in the header of the script, separating options with a semicolon:

```py
##Units=selection Millimeter;Centimeter;Meter
```

And later in the script you can get the chosen value in this way:

```py
if Units == 0:
    # User chose millimeter
elif Units == 1:
    # User chose centimeter
elif Units == 2:
    # User chose meter
```

For reference, here you have an [example script](https://github.com/gacarrillor/QGIS-Resources/blob/master/collections/processing_scripts/processing/Export_Composers_of_Multiple_Projects.py).

Comment: Thanks a lot but I am limited to QGIS v2.8, is there a way to do it in v2.8?

Answer (score 0):

The *selection* option **does** work on QGIS 2.18.2 (Las Palmas). Please note that the selection parameter will get an integer value,starting from 0, (and not a string value) correspond to the order of the string as you write it in your selection (just like in Germán Carrillo answer).